# Media Capture and Upload as Content Version or attachment?

Tags: phonegap, mobilesdk, salesforcetouchplatform

I am building a functionality using mobile SDK.I have a requirement on capturing video and uploading to salesforce attachment or content version Object?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions

I referred the above document from phone gap but i am stuck as to how do i convert the media file to necessary format through the Javascript and upload as attachment?If anyone familiar with this it may be quite helpful to get some code .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also, here's another example of using the PhoneGap Media API. In my case, I was capturing Audio, but it shouldn't be that different to capture Video and upload it to Salesforce - http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/03/speech-recognition-att-toolkit.html. 
You can find the full code base for that sample app on GitHub - https://github.com/sbhanot-sfdc/ATT-Toolkit-Speech-to-Text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent !Thank you !I will dig into this .Thanks i have something to start.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing from PhoneGap with Photos. The image data is Base64 which, happily, is just what you need to send to the REST API. Here's the relevant code:

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData, name, contactId) {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    SFHybridApp.logToConsole("in onPhotoDataSuccess, contactId = "+contactId);

    // Update the image on screen
    $j('#Image').attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);

    // Upload the image data to Content
    $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    forcetkClient.create('ContentVersion', {
        "PathOnClient" : name + ".png",
        "VersionData" : imageData
    }, function(data){
        // Now update the Contact record with the new ContentVersion Id
        SFHybridApp.logToConsole('Created ContentVersion ' + data.id);
        forcetkClient.update('Contact', contactId, { 
            "Image_ID__c" : data.id 
        }, function(){
            $j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            SFHybridApp.logToConsole('Updated Contact '+contactId);
        }, onErrorSfdc);
    }, onErrorSfdc);    
}
```

More detail in the article [Developing Hybrid Apps with the Salesforce Mobile SDK](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK)

Comment: @metadady That was excellent !!Just one more question the one here is for image so we just did base64 encoded .Any idea on how will handle for the video?

Comment: Looks like you get a File URI for video, rather than Base64 data, so you'll have to read data from the file, base64 encode it if necessary, and put it in the VersionData field, I think.

Comment: thanks !Much appreciated the quick response !Sandeep has also provided me some solid code on how to approach this to fetch data from file .Excellent article developing for Hybrid Apps.Thanks for that